# Hide php page name of header function in url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to hide the php page name in url which redirects after login by header function. So far I can hide the index file but can't hide the file which redirects after login. Here are my codes,

**PHP script for after login events**

```
$sql_login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sms_people WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_login);
if ($row > 0 && $row[5] == 1) {
header('Location: adminpanel.php');
}
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

How can I hide the files which redirects from header function by using `.htaccess` file? Need this help badly. Tnx.

Comment: Are you trying to do URL rewriting? https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: I've already seen the link but can't find my solution there. Tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got a solution. I changed the information in header function & placed the file corresponding to the given information in `.htaccess` file. Here are the codes,

**PHP Script**

```
if ($row > 0 && $row[5] == 1) {
header('Location: AdminPanel');    // Instead of adminpanel.php
}
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule    ^AdminPanel/?$    adminpanel.php    [R,NC,L]    // Added this line.
```

Tnx for all your efforts btw.

Answer (score 0):

there is an alternative way to redirect php files and hide them

for example
http://yourwebsite.com/user/login/

user part main user.php or you can change the file name

firstl, in your htaccess redirect to index php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
###############  SEO     ##########################
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

in your index.php file

```
    $rootfolder="parts"

    if(isset($_GET["url"])){
    $part= explode("/", $_GET["url"]);

    if(isset($part[0]))
         $controller = ''.strtolower($part[0]).'';
    if(isset($parca[1]))
         $method   = ''.strtolower($part[1]).'';
    if(isset($parca[2]))
         $id    = ''.$part[2].'';

    if( file_exists($rootfolder."/".$controller.php))
    {
    //you can call the file if it is exits
requre_once $rootfolder."/".$controller.php;
    }else{
    die("404 not found !");
    }

    }
```